# Seeking Farm Resource Regions shapefiles?

Tags: data, united-states

Could someone direct me to the potential sources to find the Shapefiles of farm resource regions?

The map exactly looks like the one here https://www.usda.gov/media/blog/2014/04/22/celebrating-our-glorious-planet

[image]

but I have had a hard time finding the Shapefiles.

Comment: If you are seeking open data then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

Data.gov is my first stop for US Federal government data. Searching for for "farm resource regions" yielded 19,446 results. Filtering by `geospatial` and `agricultural` narrowed it down to [4 search results](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?metadata_type=geospatial&groups=agriculture8571&q=farm%20resource%20regions&sort=score%20desc%2C%20name%20asc). The first two sound promising:

1. [Major Land Resource Areas (MLRA)](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/major-land-resource-areas-mlra-of-the-united-states-the-caribbean-and-the-pacific-basin-na)

   > "The United States, Caribbean and Pacific Basin Major Land Resource Areas (MLRA) Geographic Database serves as the geospatial expression of the map products presented and described in Agricultural Handbook 296 (2006). Land resource categories historically used at State and national levels are land resource units, land resource areas, and **land resource regions**." *-excerpt from data product description (emphasis added)*

   Is a "land resource region" the same as a "farm resource region"?
2. [National Coordinated Common Resource Areas (CRA) Geographic Database](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/common-resource-areas-cra-of-the-united-states-the-caribbean-and-the-pacific-basin-nationa)

   > "A Common Resource Area (CRA) map delineation is defined as a geographical area where resource concerns, problems, or treatment needs are similar. It is considered a subdivision of an existing Major Land Resource Area (MLRA) map delineation or polygon. Landscape conditions, soil, climate, human considerations, and other natural resource information are used to determine the geographic boundaries of a Common Resource Area." *-excerpt from data product description*

To actually download both datasets, Data.gov re-directs you to the main page of the [USDA Geospatial Data Gateway](https://datagateway.nrcs.usda.gov/). In the bottom-right corner of this page, you'll see a box that says "I want to..." with links to different ways to download data.

[image]

Through the interactive map, you can download "Common Resource Areas by State." There's no way to preview the data, so I couldn't tell for sure if this is the data you wanted. Since it's divided by state anyway, I suggest downloading a single state and loading it into your GIS to make sure it's what you want before you download all 50 states.

[image]

---

Along the way I found a couple other data sources that might be useful:

- [Data Products page on USDA.gov](https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products.aspx)
- [USDA geospatial APIs](https://www.ers.usda.gov/developer/geospatial-apis/) - many data layers available as REST services (see [How to open REST/JSON service in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273842/how-to-open-rest-json-service-in-qgis) for instructions)

Comment: Thanks. I still could not find what I would love to find. However, I really appreciate your efforts of helping me. It's also great to browse these sites as a learning experience.

Comment: So the "common resource areas" aren't the same as the "farm resource areas"? I was afraid of that. There didn't seem to be data set with exactly the same name. There's a comment section under the blog post, it might be worth making a request there. IANAL, but I'm pretty sure the Freedom of Information Act guarantees you access to that data if you ask for it, as long as it's not classified.

Answer (score 0):

Look here under "U.S. Farm Resource Regions" you can get an excel file with all of the regions appended to the FIPS code.

https://www.ers.usda.gov/data-products/arms-farm-financial-and-crop-production-practices/documentation.aspx